# Is there a way to map a network drive (w/credentials) working with Boost?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, networkcredentials

I have the following code to check if a directory exists.

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace boost::filesystem;

try
{
    // Check whether the directory is valid
    if (!exists(dir) || !is_directory(dir))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
catch (filesystem_error const & e)
{
    return false;
}
```

Unfortunately it catches an error when trying to navigate to a folder on another PC on the network. If I try navigating to the folder using Windows explorer I am prompted for a username and password. If I enter these details and then run my code again it can find the folder and doesn't catch an error.

Is there any way I can enter network credentials in the code if I know what they will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network credentials are completely unrelated to traversing filesystems.

Instead, on windows, map the drive (e.g. use `NET USE`).

Then you will be able to browse the mapped drive as any other location.

So, direct answer: **No.** There is no way enter credentials with Boost. Neither should there be.

Comment: This set me off in the right direction. I ended up finding and using WNetAddConnection2A as a way of mapping a drive. I was then able to use Boost from that mapped drive. Thanks.